# get substring and replace with previous text in java

Tags: java, string, replaceall

i get crawled website from bean via getWebsite(). I get website some time http://www.stackoverflow.com and some time get http://stackoverflow.com. My question is i want to replace with "info@stackoverflow.com" to setEmail() to bean instead of that. Is it possible with help of substring and replaceAll method?

i tried myself on bellow

```
    String s=str.substring(0,11);
    System.out.println("String s (0,11) :"+s);
    String string=str.substring(0,7);
    System.out.println("string  (0,7):"+string);
    String name=str.substring(11);
    String name1=str.substring(7);
    System.out.println("name  :"+name);
    boolean b=((!(s.length()==11)) || (string.length()==7))? true : ((!(string.length()==7)) || (s.length()==11))? false : true ;
    System.out.println(b);
    if(b==true)
    {
        System.out.println("condition TRUE");
        String replaceString=string.replaceAll(string,"info@");
        System.out.println("replaceString  :"+replaceString+name1);
    }
    if(b==false) 
    {
        System.out.println("condition FALSE");
        String replaceString=s.replaceAll(s,"info@");
        System.out.println("replaceString  :"+replaceString+name);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this looks like a code obfuscation contest winner.  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

ok don't give yourself a hard time on it, just replace the `http://` or the other possible patterns using the `str.replaceAll()` in the string with `info@`. Using a regular expression is recommended

```
String str = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

str = str.replaceAll("http:\\/\\/(www\\.)?","info@");
System.out.println(str);
```

http://rextester.com/SJD79549

well my question is? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
String orig = "Hello World!";

String repl = orig.substring(6, 11); // "World"

String newstr = orig.replaceAll(repl, "user1937829"); // Hello user1937829!
```

In your case, you don't need `http://(www)`

```
String newstr = orig.replaceAll("www", "").replaceAll("http://", "info@");
```

`newstr` will be equal to `info@stackoverflow.com` if `orig` is `http://www.stackoverflow.com` or `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Hope this is all you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expression in replace function

```
String str1= "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
String str2 = "http://stackoverflow.com";
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("http:\\/\\/(www\\.)?","info@"));
System.out.println(str2.replaceAll("http:\\/\\/(www\\.)?","info@"));
```